# Lane-Emden. Quasi-linearization method

Tags: astronomy, computational-physics, boundary-conditions

ow to prove this theorem? I have a doubt.

**Theroem:** Suppose that $w(x,\alpha)$ solved
$\ddot{w}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{w}+\alpha^{2}w=0$ with $w(0)=1$,
$\dot{w}(0)=0$, $w(1)=0$.
Then $v(x,\alpha) := \omega w(x,\alpha)$ solves
$\ddot{v}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{v}+\Theta^{2}v^{n}=0$ with $v(0)=\omega$,
$\dot{v}(0)=0$, $v(1)=0$ provided that
\begin{equation}
  \omega = \left(\frac{\alpha^{2}}{\Theta^{2}}\right)^{1/(n-1)}.
  \end{equation}

*Demonstration:*

- \begin{equation} v(0) = \omega w(0) = \omega 1 = \omega\end{equation}
- \begin{equation} \dot{v}(0) = \omega \dot{w}(0) = \omega 0 = 0\end{equation}
- \begin{equation} v(1) = \omega w(1) = \omega 0 = 0\end{equation}
- Substituting $v=\omega w$ into $\ddot{v}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{v}+\Theta^{2}v^{n}=0$ and cancelling common factors, we obtain $\ddot{w}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{w}+\alpha^{2}w^{n}=0$.

My question is:
$\ddot{w}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{w}+\alpha^{2}w=0$ then $\ddot{w}+\frac{2}{x}\dot{w}+\alpha^{2}w^{n}=0$? I guess not. I can´t demostrate this last part of the theorem.

Referene: Boyd, J. P. (2011). Chebyshev spectral methods and the Lane-Emden problem. Numerical Mathematics: Theory, Methods and Applications, 4(2), 142-157.

Comment: I suspect a typo in your first equation: $\alpha^2 w$ should read $\alpha^2 w^n$. Otherwise it seems imposible with $\omega$ being a constant.

Comment: I think so. I think there is an errata but it's wtritten like that in the article.

Comment: I looked at the article. I think it is clear that they mistyped the equation Their strategy is scale $x$ and $v$ and nothing cleverer.

Comment: I totally agree with you but my mate insisted i should chek it again. Thank you 'mike stone'.